# MySQL query works on mysqlworkbench but not on php environment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that perfectly works under MySQL workbench program with MySQL 5.6 version, but when I try to test the same query in a PHP environment I got the error below:

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "response": {
    "error": {
      "description": "Query error",
      "error": {
        "errorInfo": [
          "42000",
          1064,
          "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')t1 HAVING price > 0 AND price < 804' at line 1"
        ]
      },
      "query": null
    }
  }
}
```

The query is this one:

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT t.id, 
          t.user_id , 
          t.invoice_num, 
          t.registration, 
          SUM(t.price) as price
   FROM t_0 t 
   WHERE t.brandid=587
   GROUP BY t.invoice_num)t1 
   HAVING price > 0 AND price < 12
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

In the PHP environment I'm just using the PDO connection for execute the query in this way:

```
$test_query = "here the query that I have";
$result = $con->query($test_query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Can someone explain to me what could cause the problem?
From my side, it seems pretty much correct as syntax.

Comment: The error is showing a different criteria for price, compared to the sql. So maybe you should show the php code snippet that uses your query? But I think the HAVING should be put inside the sub-query. It's a part of the GROUP BY.  Or change the HAVING to a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks @LukStorm for the reply. I have updated my question with the php part.

Comment: Regarding the GROUP BY function I think that it can also stay outside the sub-query. Also because otherwise also the mysqlworkbench program would give me an error.

Comment: I have also changed the HAVING with the WHERE condition and in mysqlworkbench it works in both cases. But on php env it gets the same output error.

Comment: Well, can't help you much with the php code (not my cup of tea).  But regarding the SQL, I know MySql allows to select fields without aggregation function that are not in the group by. But on other databases or depending on a setting that wouldn't be allowed.  So I wonder that when it runs it via PHP that it uses the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting.  You could try with using MAX for `t.id, t.user_id , t.registration`. Since you're using the SUM, the GROUP BY and HAVING should be in the sub-query.

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestions, I'll give a try. I would like to ask you if there is also a way to optimize better the query by avoiding the subquery structure and get the same result.

Comment: It would have been to much for a comment, so I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing the query to something that would work in almost any database?
(almost, because `LIMIT` can be database specific. F.e. MS SQL Server uses `TOP` instead)

```
SELECT 
 MAX(t.id) AS id, 
 MAX(t.user_id) AS user_id, 
 t.invoice_num, 
 MAX(t.registration) AS registration, 
 SUM(t.price) as price
FROM t_0 t 
WHERE t.brandid = 587
GROUP BY t.invoice_num
HAVING SUM(t.price) BETWEEN 1 AND 11
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```